# About viewController's "viewDidLoad" and "viewWillAppear" methods

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, viewdidload, viewwillappear

I've got a question regarding the two mentioned methods, since in my tests I don´t make clear the order they are called. I thought that, firstly, `viewDidLoad` is called when the viewController is loaded for first time (as the name indicates), and inmediately after the init method. Then, I thought that once `viewDidLoad` returns, `viewWillAppear` is called. If you display another viewController, and then you return to this one, then it should be already loaded and only `viewWillAppear` will be called.

However, while developing I make the impression that there is no order when calling `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`... I couldn´t find a clear description of this lifecycle in Apple's documentation, how does this actually work?

Thanks!

Comment: "viewDidLoad is called when the viewController is loaded for first time (as the name indicates)" - It confused me for a long time too. The view controller and its view are different things. This is one of the most important (and fundamental) things you have to understand about view controllers.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would like to add to Caleb's answer: Don't confuse the view controller and the view! The name `viewDidLoad` clearly indicates that the method is invoked after the **view** has been loaded. It is the view controller that does the loading.

Some pointers regarding the lifecycle of views and the order in which messages are sent:

- Not an official Apple document, but I find [this diagram](http://rdkw.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/ios-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle/) really useful because it includes pretty much all of `UIViewController`'s lifecycle overrides.
- In the section [Resource Management in View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html) from Apple's "View Controller Programming Guide" there is a flowchart that depicts how views are initially loaded. It explains `loadView` and `viewDidLoad`, also in conjunction with storyboards.
- The section [Responding to Display-Related Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDisplay-Notifications/RespondingtoDisplay-Notifications.html) from Apple's "View Controller Programming Guide" explains how to respond to views appearing and disappearing (`viewWillAppear:` et al)
- If you are planning on implementing a container view controller: The [UIViewController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has a good overview of how messages need to be sent by your subclass.

I'm stopping here. You can find more stuff yourself by googling for "uiviewcontroller life cycle".

Comment: That [UIViewController lifecycle diagram](http://rdkw.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/ios-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle/) is superb. Thanks for the link.

Comment: It's worth noting that viewWillUnload is deprecated in iOS 6 ("views are no longer purged under low-memory conditions and so this method is never called"). The bottom-left part of the Lifecycle Diagram doesn't apply to modern iOS apps. The rest of the diagram is very useful though, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

`-viewDidLoad` is called when the controller loads its view, which is not necessarily right after initialization. View controllers don't load their views until they need them, either to display or for any other reason.

`-viewWillAppear` is called just before the view is displayed. This will be after `-viewDidLoad`, but you don't know exactly how long after. `-viewWillAppear` is called every time the view is displayed; `-viewDidLoad` will only be called a second time if the view is unloaded at some point (such as [didReceiveMemoryWarning](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/didReceiveMemoryWarning)). These days that's unusual, but it can happen.

Or if the viewController is set to `nil`, which can usually happen if a view controller is kicked off the navigation stack, and therefore next time it is brought to the navigation stack it needs to call `-viewDidLoad` again.

Comment: also, all your Outlets that you might have set up in Interface Builder are hooked up, when `viewDidLoad` is called.

Answer (score 3):

> I thought that, firstly, viewDidLoad is called when the viewController
>   is loaded for first time (as the name indicates), and inmediately after the init method

No. The name indicates that the controller's `view` has been loaded (not the controller itself). Actually the docs state that this method will get called after the view hierarchy has been loaded into memory (either via `loadView` or through a nib for example).

> Then, I thought that once viewDidLoad returns, viewWillAppear is
>   called

Again, no. `loadView` (and as a consequence `viewDidLoad`) method will get called the first time that `view` property is to be accessed and is `nil` (which is the case when you're initializing a controller). Think of this simple scenario:

```
MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
UIView *view = vc.view; // <= loadView & viewDidLoad will fire but it certainly didn't appear...
```

> However, while developing I make the impression that there is no order
>   when calling viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear...

Well there is an order. We know for sure that `viewWillAppear` will always be called after `viewDidLoad` (if both of them are to be called of course).

Comment: So, the point is that there is an order if both methods are called, but `viewDidLoad` hasn't necessarily to return before `viewWillAppear` being called?

Comment: The point is that the methods aren't 'linked' in any way. `viewDidLoad` is about loading the hierarchy into the memory, while `viewWillAppear` is called when the view is about to be added into a hierarchy (for presentation). `viewDidLoad` _always_ returns before `viewWillAppear`.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, *ViewDidLoad* is only calling once after loading the view. So we can initialize the instances in the *viewDidLoad*. It is mainly meant for the initialization.

*viewWillAppear* will invoke whenever we reach to this view. So if there is any changes in UI, we can done it in *viewWillAppear*.

Answer (score 0):

I ran a trace on when all these calls are made: http://thecodist.com/article/ios_arc_storyboards_and_uiviewcontroller_trace