# Push New View Controller From Subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a UITableViewController as a subview of my UIViewController. The table view is populated from an RSS feed and that works fine. I'm trying to push a webviewcontroller onto my main navigation stack when a row in the subview is selected but I'm not sure how to get it to work. I know my current code would work correctly if I was using the UITableViewController on it's own and not as a subview.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    self.title = @"Home";

    GRSNewsViewController *newsView = [[GRSNewsViewController alloc]init];
    [self addChildViewController:newsView];
    [self.view addSubview:newsView.view];
}
```

UITableViewController .h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class RSSChannel;
@class WebViewController;

@interface GRSNewsViewController : UITableViewController <NSXMLParserDelegate>
{
    NSURLConnection *connection;
    NSMutableData *xmlData;
    RSSChannel *channel;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong)WebViewController *webViewController;

- (void)fetchEntries;


@end
```

My UITableViewController .m:

```
#import "GRSNewsViewController.h"
#import "RSSChannel.h"
#import "RSSItem.h"
#import "WebViewController.h"
#import "GRSHomeViewController.h"

@interface GRSNewsViewController ()

@end

@implementation GRSNewsViewController
@synthesize webViewController;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 69, 320, 173) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine];
    [self.tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    NSLog(@"%@ found a %@ element", self, elementName);
    if ([elementName isEqual:@"channel"])
    {
        channel = [[RSSChannel alloc]init];

        [channel setParentParserDelegate:self];

        [parser setDelegate:channel];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[channel items]count];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 50;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];
    }

    RSSItem *item = [[channel items]objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ssZ"];
    NSDate *pubDate = [formatter dateFromString:[item date]];
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:pubDate];

    [[cell textLabel]setText:[item title]];
    [[cell detailTextLabel]setText:dateString];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    return cell;
}

- (void)fetchEntries
{
    xmlData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://onmyhonorband.com/rss"];

    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:req delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];

    if (self)
    {
        [self fetchEntries];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [xmlData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)conn
{   
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:xmlData];

    [parser setDelegate:self];

    [parser parse];

    xmlData = nil;

    [[self tableView] reloadData];

    NSLog(@"%@\n %@\n %@\n", channel, [channel title], [channel infoString]);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    connection = nil;

    xmlData = nil;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [[webViewController webView]loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]]];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];

    RSSItem *entry = [[channel items]objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[entry link]];

    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [[webViewController webView]loadRequest:req];
    webViewController.hackyURL = url;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: You should check if self.navigationController is nil. You probably should use [self.parentViewController.navigationController push...].

Comment: Not related: you are calling subview a childViewController..a subview is a view..moreover you are parsing a file in the viewController..is not architecturally speaking correct.

Comment: @rdelmar, This is the message I get in the console: Application tried to push a nil view controller on target <GRSNavController: 0x9d1f340>.

Comment: Where did you initialize `webViewController`?

Comment: @Julian, I've added my .h file

Comment: initialize not declare, he asked where do you initialize it. i.e. where do you create webViewController? Declaring it as a property is not creating it. You can't use something without creating it i.e. you need to alloc it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out in the comments, and as indicated by the console message you get, your primary problem is that you never initialize `webViewController`. Add a line that looks something like this to your table view controller's `initWithStyle:` initializer.

```
self.webViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] init];
```

Other things that I spotted:

- In `viewDidLoad` you alloc/init a new `UITableView`. You should not do this because you are overwriting the `UITableView` instance that was already created by the `UITableViewController` base class in `loadView`. Check out [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17362443/1054378) for more info about the lifecycle of views and view controllers.
- In the parent view controller you forgot to invoke `didMoveToParentViewController`. You need to do this after you call `addChildViewController`. Read the section "Implementing a Container View Controller" in the [UIViewController class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

If UIViewController addSubView a view of UITableViewController,you want to push in the method of tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath,you should check if     self.navigationController is nil. If it's nil,You probably should use

```
[self.parentViewController.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

if self.parentViewController is also nil,Sometimes,you have to set a @property to point out the parentViewController In UITableViewController,like:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIViewController *parentVC;
```

and in UIViewController:

```
UITableViewController *tableViewVC = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
tableViewVC.parentVC = self;
```

In UITableViewController ,-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
[self.parentVC.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

When you execute :

```
NSLog(@"‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️self.navigationController is%@,\n 
self.parentViewController.navigationController is %@,\n 
self.parentVC.navigationController is %@",self.navigationController,self.parentViewController.navigationController,self.parentVC.navigationController);
```

It may print as:

```
‼️‼️‼️‼️‼️self.navigationController is(null),
self.parentViewController.navigationController is (null),
self.parentVC.navigationController is <UINavigationController: 0x7af32ae0>
```