# Blank screen after share content using UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I share some contents using the following code

```
var textToShare = "Test"
let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [textToShare], applicationActivities: nil)
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact]

presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But when I press the cancel button or when the content is shared successfully, the App shows a blank screen.

How to fix this issue ?

**UPDATE**:

The blank screen just appears when I select mail or sms apps for the sharing target, For Telegram, Twitter and Facebook it is working perfect.

I commented all the code inside lifecycle methods, Still same issue.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    //setControlsAreHidden(true)
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    //if dataAddedToView
    //{
    //     activityIndicator?.removeFromSuperview()
    //}

}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool)
{
    //setControlsAreHidden(false)
}
```

Comment: this demo project may help you: https://github.com/genedelisa/ActivityDemo

Comment: I've checked your code, and in my project it works correctly, I think maybe problem can be somewhere in `viewWillAppear` of your presenting view controller. Can you share more code?

Comment: Yes I think the problem is in code that you're not showing.  Code in the presenting view controller would relevant.

Comment: are you doing this on the main thread? could you show us what code you have at obvious points in the presentation lifecycle?

Comment: @VitaliyGozhenko I don't have any code inside viewWillAppear

Comment: @robdashnash Check the updated question, I don't have any code inside lifecycle methods

Comment: Please show your code for your `completionWithItemsHandler` and dismissing the activity controller.

Comment: Better if you can share the code with dropbox for now.

Comment: Just throwing it out there, but your overrides should be calling the super method.  e.g. `override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) { super.viewDidAppear(animated) }`.  Some base view controllers do work in these functions.

Comment: Hello, is it possible to reproduce this problem in 2022? My team is afraid of using Share Activity because they had this problem in the past. Resulting in much inferior user experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having this same problem, and was able to solve it by adjust the sizing constraints of my primary UIView.

Code before:

```
override func loadView() {
    self.view                                           = UIView()
    self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
}
```

Code after:

```
override func loadView() {
    self.view                                           = UIView()
}
```

So just remove `self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

This might not apply to everyone, but based on other peoples' answers, I gather there are various issues with how views are displayed which can cause the same problem. If my fix doesn't work for you, I suggest commenting out all unnecessary code until the problem goes away, and then methodically bring small bits back online, testing along the way to identify your issue.

Comment: by doing this it won't display a blank screen anymore but the constraints are incorrect for me. so it won't display like it should

Comment: Yes, root view should not be set as: translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false; thumb up.

Comment: Is it possible to reproduce the problem in 2022?

Answer (score 2):

As you are presenting `MFMailComposeViewController` and `MFMessageComposeViewController`  above your current `UIViewController` so when you dismiss the `MFMailComposeViewController` or `MFMessageComposeViewController` after sending the message then your `UIViewController` `viewWillAppear` method will be called as the view is appearing again, so in my opinion check in `viewWillAppear` or `viewWillDisappear` method whether you are making your view `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first check that your view controller is not being destroyed while you're presenting content.  Some debug statements in the presenting view controller's lifecycle management routines (e.g., ViewWillDisappear) could help.

If the problem stems from the ViewController disappearing, you'll need to recreate it appropriately.

Also look at any place where you provide content: is it being triggered to draw at the right times?

Additionally, ensure you're using APIs as required (e.g., calling the superclass in all methods where it's required, such as the view controller lifecycle routines).  See:

- [SO ViewController methods question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17362095/about-viewcontrollers-viewdidload-and-viewwillappear-methods)
- [SO ViewController lifecycle question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562938/looking-to-understand-the-ios-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle)
- [Apple UIViewController reference (latest)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/)

These are the areas I would focus my attention on and/or provide the relevant code for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any calls to the super implementation in your viewDidAppear, viewWillAppear or viewWillDisappear methods.

What happens if you do?:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    //setControlsAreHidden(true)
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    //if dataAddedToView
    //{
    //     activityIndicator?.removeFromSuperview()
    //}

}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    //setControlsAreHidden(false)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But the issue not fixed :(

Comment: Are you using a navigation controller? Maybe you'd need to present it from there instead? Like navigationController. presentViewController(...)?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're not presenting the activity view controller in the proper view, try something like this:

```
if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")){
   activityViewController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
}
```

It's a objective C code, but just as example of how to set the view.

If you need how to check the iOS version:

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
```